# better determination of the saved id

Tags: c, linux, process

I'm trying to see how a process can get its own saved-set-uid. The only way I could get `suid` is with `getresuid()`, but it's not the best solution I guess.

How can I get it in a "more engineering way"?

This is my code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    uid_t *ruid = malloc(sizeof (uid_t));
    uid_t *euid = malloc(sizeof (uid_t));
    uid_t *suid = malloc(sizeof (uid_t));

    getresuid(ruid, euid, suid);
    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", *ruid, *euid, *suid);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `getresuid` is not the best solution?  What does "more engineering way" mean?

Comment: Also, there's no need to dynamically allocate memory.  Just create three variables of type `uid_t` and pass their addresses to the function.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the way to do it. Your approach is just overly complicated. Have a look at this:

```
uid_t ruid, euid, suid;
getresuid(&ruid, &euid, &suid);
printf("%d, %d, %d\n", ruid, euid, suid);
```